# ORACLE - Redefinir una tabla con Enterprise Manager

Tags: oracle

A la hora de reorganizar el contenido de una tabla mediante el Enterprise Manager me pide unas credenciales de host. La verdad es que no sé qué es lo que va ahí. He probado con las cuentas de Oracle pero todas me dan el siguiente error:

```
Se ha producido un error al verificar las credenciales de host. 
Asegúrese de que las credenciales son válidas y de que especifican una cuenta con privilegios suficientes para escribir en el directorio en el que se creará el archivo de comandos de reorganización.
Error de verificación de credenciales: ERROR: Contraseña errónea para el usuario
```

Comment: ¿Como tienes configurado el Enterprise Manager? ¿Has ingresado alguna ves alguna dirección del servidor de base de datos, el nombre de la instancia, el usuario y contraseña?

Comment: Del mensaje de error, me queda claro que lo que te pide es una cuenta del sistema operativo donde está instalado el servidor, que tenga privilegios suficientes _para escribir en el directorio en el que se creará el archivo de comandos de reorganización_

Comment: Era eso lo que pasaba. No le había dado al usuario del SO los permisos para escribir en la base de Datos. Muchas gracias!